# ROS using C++ 11 & How to Use With Catkin?

Tags: ros, catkin, eclipse, c++11

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is ROS compiled using c++ 11 with catkin? I suspect not since I am getting an error trying to use {} initializer for a vector, i.e. c++98...must be initialized...

For at least my builds where in the catkin files would I add the '-std=c++11' option?

I am using Eclipse but I think this is controlled via the cmake files, not a project property.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216842/ros-using-c++-11-&-how-to-use-with-catkin?/) by [Rud](https://answers.ros.org/users/19820/rud/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2015-08-31

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rud](https://answers.ros.org/users/19820/rud/) on 2015-09-01**:
I poked around and found that adding the "-std-c++11" in the file flags.make worked. But I suspect it will be overwritten the next time I add a file to the CMakeLists.txt. Just wanted to mention this with the warning. The file was overwritten with the changes to the C*.txt file.

**Comment by [Rud](https://answers.ros.org/users/19820/rud/) on 2015-09-01**:
Both answers provided worked. I flagged the one by Julius as 'correct' since it was more succinct. I added the line to just below the ## Build ## box, just fyi. Appreciated also the link to ROS/C++11 points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All the current distributions of ROS are compiled using C++03.

You can compile your own packages using c++11 by adding the following line to the CMakeLists.txt of your project:

```
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
```

Note that it is recomended to have checks for c++11 features at configure time and provide equivalent functionality with extra compiler features. This is only required if you are planning to release the ROS packages that you develop. If you are only planning to use your packages yourself then you can just c++11 functionality.
You can read more about ROS and C++11 here:
[link text](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#c)

---

Originally posted by [JuliusGel](https://answers.ros.org/users/20679/juliusgel/) with karma: 433 on 2015-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 25

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rud](https://answers.ros.org/users/19820/rud/) on 2015-09-01**:
Thanks for the answer. I am at the moment only developing for myself. It will be awhile before I would attempt adding to ROS itself.

**Comment by [marcozorzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26988/marcozorzi/) on 2016-06-02**:
Worked like a charm for me too. Thanks!

**Comment by [vik748](https://answers.ros.org/users/29926/vik748/) on 2017-07-10**:
Is there a way to add this flag for an individual file and not the entire project?

**Comment by [JuliusGel](https://answers.ros.org/users/20679/juliusgel/) on 2017-07-11**:
You could try SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES( foo.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -std=c++11). I have, however, not tried this and I am not sure how this will affect ABI compatibility in your executable.

**Comment by [Ashkr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45549/ashkr/) on 2020-07-01**:
@JuliusGel; thanks man, it works for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to add

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

to the CMakeLists.txt of your package.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-09-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-09-01**:
Also consult this: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Cxx11AbiCompatibility Not sure if ROS is compiled to be ABI compatible between C++ versions.

**Comment by [Rud](https://answers.ros.org/users/19820/rud/) on 2015-09-01**:
Thanks for the answer.